# Standard function for replacing subsequences

Tags: function, replace, lisp, common-lisp, sequence

Quite often I need to replace subsequence of certain elements with another sequence of the same type, but, probably with different length. Implementation of such function is no challenge, this is what I use now:

```
(defun substitute* (new old where &key key (test #'eql))
  (funcall (alambda (rest)
             (aif (search old rest :key key :test test)
                  (concatenate (etypecase rest
                                 (string 'string)
                                 (vector 'vector)
                                 (list 'list))
                               (subseq rest 0 it)
                               new
                               (self (subseq rest (+ it (length old)))))
                  rest))
           where))
```

Works like this:

```
CL-USER> (substitute* '(x y) '(z) '(1 z 5 8 y z))
(1 X Y 5 8 Y X Y)
CL-USER> (substitute* "green button" "red button"
                      "here are red indicator, red button and red wire")
"here are red indicator, green button and red wire"
CL-USER> (substitute* #(4) #(2 2) #(2 2 2 2 2))
#(4 4 2)
```

You see, it's very handy and useful, so I've feeling that I'm reinventing wheel and it must be in the standard library, I just don't know its name (sometimes names are not obvious, you may search for `filter` while what you need is `set-difference`).

As a result of compromise between clarity and efficiency:

```
(defun substitute* (new old where &key key (test #'eql))
  (let ((type (etypecase where
                (string 'string)
                (vector 'vector)
                (list 'list)))
        (new (coerce new 'list))
        (old (coerce old 'list))
        (where (coerce where 'list)))
    (coerce (funcall (alambda (rest)
                       (aif (search old rest :key key :test test)
                            (append (remove-if (constantly t) rest :start it)
                                    new
                                    (self (nthcdr (+ it (length old)) rest)))
                            rest))
                     where)
            type)))
```

Comment: why would one use funcall + alambda, instead of a plain `LABELS`? Also you are using recursion + concatenate. Looks like a lot of intermediate garbage.

Comment: If one uses `lambda` to make things shorter and convenient, why not to use `alambda` for the same reason? I think `alambda` looks better and less nested. What for intermediate garbage.. well, we have garbage collector in LISP, don't we? Is my code dangerous or bad?

Comment: You could use `replace` (together with `copy-seq` if you don't want the function to be destructive) instead of `concatenate` and `subseq`.

Comment: @Rörd, if resulting string is shorter than original one, there may be bug.

Comment: LABELS is a common idiom. 'Is my code dangerous or bad?' No, just extremely inefficient. Having a garbage collector does not mean you should write your software in a way that it's mostly busy with memory management.

Comment: @Rörd The replace and copy-seq is absolutely right **if** the sequence to "splice in" is the same length as the subsequence to be replaced, but I think that's not the case, as per "I need to replace subsequence of certain elements with another sequence of the same type, but, probably with *different length*".

Comment: @RainerJoswig, you're right about inefficiency of my code, I'm gonna fix it. 'LABELS is a common idiom.' May be not all these useful things in LISP have become common idioms at once... I think `alambda` and `aif` are very handy.

Comment: The `alambda` and `aif` are just macros that expand to the corresponding `labels`.  There's nothing the matter with using them, but because they're less common, people won't recognize them right away.

Comment: @Mark I see your update, but you're still concatenating a whole lot of extra stuff.  `(reduce #'grow …)` is essentially `(reduce (lambda (…) (concatenate …)) …)` which is essentially `(concatenate … (concatenate … (concatenate …)))`.  The outside calls to `concatenate` are copying the results from the earlier calls, so your memory usage is quadratic in terms of the input size.  Just because it's not in an explicit recursion doesn't mean that it uses any less space.  For lists, you can avoid copying the tails by using `append` (as in `(append x (append y (append z …)))` because `append` doesn't

Comment: copy its last argument.  For vectors, you really need to pre-allocate the sequence that's big enough (or use a vector will a fill pointer that you can extend, which is perhaps an approach I should have implemented, too), and copy the elements into it, because there's no concatenate/append function that works on vectors that doesn't copy the inputs.  It's just the way the data structures are.

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you're asking now;  `mapc` is just like `mapcar`, except that it returns the original list, not a list of results.  E.g., if you `(mapc #'grow '(x y z))`, you're just calling `(grow 'x)`, `(grow 'y)`, and `(grow 'z)`, throwing out the results.  It's not equivalent at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the change to `grow` that did `(setf result …)`.  You still end up calling `concatenate` with the results to previous calls to `concatenate`.  That's going to create lots of intermediate garbage.  If you end up calling concatenate more than once, you're using more space than you need to.  It's not about the recursion.  It's about passing the results from one call to `concatenate` to another call to `concatenate`.  It doesn't matter whether it's recursive or iterative.

Comment: There's no reason you can't write in a functional style.  The point is that arrays of contiguous memory, regardless of the language, support constant time random access, but are expensive to extend, and that singly linked-lists, regardless of language, are linear time access, but constant time to extend.  The code I wrote can be written in a functional manner (modulo the fact that `replace` is destructive);  it's not about functional vs. imperative.  It's a question of the data structures.  You can make the same mistake in C, e.g., if you repeated append to a string with strcat.

Comment: Just to make the point clearer, I've added a more functional implementation of `splice-replace-list`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, what if I use `coerce` to convert input to lists, then back to supplied type? And inside I would use `append`. Even if `coerce` is as bad as `concatenate`, it will be evaluated fixed number of times: 4 for any possible length of input and number of matches. Is it still ugly?

Comment: @Mark (Replying, even though you directed at Rainer) If you coerce all your inputs to lists, and then do something clever with append, to ensure that you're not copying more than you need to, you can keep the space overhead to about twice the minimum that you need.  That's *much* better than the quadratic space overhead in your earlier code, and it very well may be an acceptable tradeoff between efficiency and clarity of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there's any standard function for this.  It's more complicated than the standard `replace` family of functions.  Those can operate destructively because you know in advance that you can replace element by element.  Even in that case, it's still somewhat difficult to do this efficiently, because the access time for lists and vectors is very different, so general-purpose functions like `subseq` can be problematic.  As [Rainer Joswig pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011337/standard-function-for-replacing-subsequences/24014487?noredirect=1#comment37017116_24014487):

> It's kind of unfortunate that for many algorithms over sequences there
>   is no single efficient implementation. I see often that there are two
>   versions, one for lists and one for vectors, which then get hidden
>   behind a dispatching function. For a hack a simple common version is
>   fine, but for a library function, often there are different
>   implementations - like shown here.

(In fact, in doing a bit of research on whether some library contains a function for this, one of the first Google results I got was a question on Code Review, [Generic sequence splitter in Common Lisp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40954/26855), in which Rainer and I both had some comment similar to those here.)

### A version for lists

However, your implementation is rather inefficient because it makes multiple copies of the the remainders of sequences.  E.g., when you replace `(z)` in `(1 z 2 z 3 z)`, with `(x y)`, you'll first make `(3 x y)`, then copy it in making `(2 x y 3 z y)`, and then you'll copy that in making `(1 x y 2 x y 3 x y)`.  You might be better off in doing one pass over the sequence, determining the indices of the subsequences to replace, or collecting the bits that need to *don't* need to be replaced, etc.  You'll probably want separate implementations for lists and for other sequences.  E.g., with a list, you might do:

```
(defun splice-replace-list (old new list)
  (do ((new (coerce new 'list)) 
       (old-len (length old))
       (parts '()))
      ((endp list)
       (reduce 'append (nreverse parts) :from-end t))
    (let ((pos (search old list)))
      (push (subseq list 0 pos) parts)
      (cond 
        ((null pos)
         (setf list nil))
        (t 
         (push new parts)
         (setf list (nthcdr (+ old-len pos) list)))))))
```

There are some optimizations you could make here, if you wanted.  For instance, you could implement a `search-list` that, rather than returning the *position* of the first instance of the sought sequence, could return a copy of the head up until that point and the tail beginning with the sequence as multiple values, or even the copied head, and the tail *after* the sequence, since that's what you're really interested in, in this case.  Additionally, you could do something a bit more efficient than `(reduce 'append (nreverse parts) :from-end t)` by not reversing `parts`, but using a reversed append.  E.g.,

```
(flet ((xappend (l2 l1)
         (append l1 l2)))
  (reduce #'xappend '((5 6) (x y) (3 4) (x y))))
;=> (x y 3 4 x y 5 6)
```

I wrote this in a somewhat imperative style, but there's no reason that you can't use a functional style if you want.  Be warned that not all Lisp implementation support tail call optimization, so it might be better to use `do`, but you certainly don't have to.  Here's a more functional version:

```
(defun splice-replace-list (old new list)
  (let ((new-list (coerce new 'list))
        (old-len (length old)))
    (labels ((keep-going (list parts)
               (if (endp list)
                   (reduce 'append (nreverse parts) :from-end t)
                   (let* ((pos (search old list))
                          (parts (list* (subseq list 0 pos) parts)))
                     (if (null pos)
                         (keep-going '() parts)
                         (keep-going (nthcdr (+ old-len pos) list)
                                     (list* new-list parts)))))))
      (keep-going list '()))))
```

### A version for vectors

For non lists, this is more difficult, because you don't have the specific sequence type that you're supposed to be using for the result.  This is why functions like `concatenate` require a result-type argument.  You can use `array-element-type` to get an element type for the input sequence, and then use `make-array` to get a sequence big enough to hold the result.  That's trickier code, and will be more complicated.  E.g., here's a first attempt. It's more complicated, but you'll get a result that's pretty close to the original vector type:

```
(defun splice-replace-vector (old new vector &aux (new-len (length new)))
  (flet ((assemble-result (length parts)
           (let ((result (make-array length :element-type (array-element-type vector)))
                 (start 0))
             (dolist (part parts result)
               (cond
                 ((consp part)
                  (destructuring-bind (begin . end) part
                    (replace result vector :start1 start :start2 begin :end2 end)
                    (incf start (- end begin))))
                 (t
                  (replace result new :start1 start)
                  (incf start new-len)))))))
    (do ((old-len (length old))
         (total-len 0)
         (start 0)
         (indices '()))
        ((null start) (assemble-result total-len (nreverse indices)))
      (let ((pos (search old vector :start2 start)))
        (cond 
          ((null pos)
           (let ((vlength (length vector)))
             (push (cons start vlength) indices)
             (incf total-len (- vlength start))
             (setf start nil)))
          (t
           (push (cons start pos) indices)
           (push t indices)
           (incf total-len (- pos start))
           (incf total-len new-len)
           (setf start (+ pos old-len))))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (splice-replace-vector '(#\z) '(#\x #\y) "12z")
"12xy"
CL-USER> (splice-replace-vector '(z) '(x y) #(x y))
#(X Y)
CL-USER> (splice-replace-vector '(z) '(x y) #(1 z 2 z 3 4 z))
#(1 X Y 2 X Y 3 4 X Y)
CL-USER> (splice-replace-vector '(#\z) #(#\x #\y) "1z2z34z")
"1xy2xy34xy"
```

If you only want to make one pass through the input vector, then you could use an adjustable array as the output, and append to it.  An adjustable array will have a bit more overhead than a fixed size array, but it does make the code a bit simpler.

```
(defun splice-replace-vector (old new vector)
  (do ((vlength (length vector))
       (vnew (coerce new 'vector))
       (nlength (length new))
       (result (make-array 0
                           :element-type (array-element-type vector)
                           :adjustable t
                           :fill-pointer 0))
       (start 0))
      ((eql start vlength) result)
    (let ((pos (search old vector :start2 start)))
      (cond
        ;; add the remaining elements in vector to result
        ((null pos)
         (do () ((eql start vlength))
           (vector-push-extend (aref vector start) result)
           (incf start)))
        ;; add the elements between start and pos to the result, 
        ;; add a copy of new to result, and increment start
        ;; accordingly
        (t 
         ;; the copying here could be improved with adjust-array,
         ;; and replace, instead of repeated calls to vector-push-extend
         (do () ((eql start pos))
           (vector-push-extend (aref vector start) result)
           (incf start))
         (loop for x across vnew
            do (vector-push-extend x result))
         (incf start (1- nlength)))))))
```

### A “generic” version

Using these two functions, you could define a general `splice-replace` that checks the type of the original input sequence and calls the appropriate function:

```
(defun splice-replace (old new sequence)
  (etypecase sequence
    (list   (splice-replace-list   old new sequence))
    (vector (splice-replace-vector old new sequence))))
```

```
CL-USER> (splice-replace #(z) '(x y) #(1 z 2 z 3 4 z))
#(1 X Y 2 X Y 3 4 X Y)
CL-USER> (splice-replace '(z) #(x y) '(1 z 2 z 3 4 z))
(1 X Y 2 X Y 3 4 X Y)
```

Comment: I want to write a function that works with all types of sequences in the same way. That's why I used `concatenate` but I didn't know that it makes copies of every argument. Now I'm gonna think about improving of my original function.

Comment: @Mark I don't mean this in a condescending way, but how else could it work?  If you `(concatenate 'list "123" "abc")`, you're getting a list back, so it has to be new (because the arguments were strings).  If you `(concatenate 'string "123" "abc")`, you're not modifying the input arguments, so you must be getting a new string, and thus copying the old strings.

Comment: @Mark OK, I've updated the answer to include a `(splice-reverse old new sequence)` that should take any types of sequences for `old` and `new`, and should give you a new sequence that's roughly the same type as `sequence`, and does a relatively minimal amount of copying.

Comment: @Mark: It's kind of unfortunate that for many algorithms over sequences there is no single efficient implementation. I see often that there are two versions, one for lists and one for vectors, which then get hidden behind a dispatching function. For a hack a simple common version is fine, but for a library function, often there are different implementations - like shown here.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, Thank for your time and explanations, I will keep this lesson in my mind. Lists are built from cons so it's easy to append something to them, while arrays occupy solid block of memory and extending means reallocation. So it's right thing to allocate memory once, like you did. I knew it, but never thought about efficiency of my LISP functions...

Comment: @Mark extending vectors *can* require allocation.  When you use an extendable vector, there's usually some surplus space so that you don't have to reallocate everytime you add something.  This is because (and why) reallocation typically doubles the amount of space for the vector.  If you end up with a vector of size n, then you only had to do log(n) reallocations to get there.